# Достать json элемент из html строки Python

Tags: python, html, json

Есть html строка. Помогите убрать лишнее и оставить только json(age, id)
Я пытался напрямую найти через ["age"], но он попросту его не видит, может я где-то ошибаюсь.

Вот html:

```
[<a class="Base name_information" name-info='{"age":"57","id":"20928"}'</a>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<a class="Base name_information" name-info='{"age":"57","id":"20928"}' </a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(json.loads(soup.a['name-info'])['age'])

57
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!